# changing apparence datatable according to attribute database jsf2 primefaces

Tags: css, flash, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I have this datatable that loadied from the datatabase, here is :

```
<p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{acceuilUserController.lc_maj}" tableStyle="width:auto">  
 <p:column headerText="Commande N° : " style="width:100px">  
 <h:outputText value="#{car.commande.id}" />  
 </p:column>  
 <p:column headerText="Date de mise à jour : " style="width:100px">  
 <h:outputText value="#{car.dateMaj}" />  
 </p:column> 
 <p:column headerText="Decision : " style="width:100px">  
 <h:outputText value="#{car.decison}" />  
 </p:column> 
 <p:column headerText="Etat : " style="width:100px">  
 <h:outputText value="#{car.etat}" />  
 </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>
```

I have another attribut `car.lu` that accept two values :`true or false`, I want when it is false the line flashes and become colored with red
how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [conditional coloring](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableColoring.jsf):

```
<p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{acceuilUserController.lc_maj}" tableStyle="width:auto" rowStyleClass=#{(car.lu == false) ? 'red' : null}>
    <p:column headerText="Commande N° : " style="width:100px">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.commande.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Date de mise à jour : " style="width:100px">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.dateMaj}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Decision : " style="width:100px">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.decison}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Etat : " style="width:100px">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.etat}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

If `car.lu` returns `false` the style class `red` is applied to the row. So you have to have this in your CSS:

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```